# run time error 1004 - vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

this my code:

```
Sub index_test()
Dim i As Double
Dim Newsht As Worksheet
Dim countnonblank1, countnonblank2 As Integer
Dim myRange, nuRange As Range
Dim nuClass As Variant
Dim inpt, Msg, Title, MyInput As String


Set Newsht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    Newsht.Name = "new_temp"

Sheets("INDEX").Columns("a:b").Copy Sheets("new_temp").Columns("b:c")

Sheets("data test").Columns("e").Copy Sheets("new_temp").Columns("a")

 Columns("A:A").Select
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$500").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

Set myRange = Columns("A:A")
countnonblank1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)
Set nuRange = Columns("B:B")
countnonblank2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)


For i = 2 To countnonblank1 + 1
**If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup**(Cells(i, 1), Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(countnonblank2 + 1, 2)), 1, 0) = "#N/A" Then
inpt = Cells(i, 1)

 Msg = "choose a new Index from the list for" & inpt & "? " _
    & vbNewLine & "äëðñåú" & vbNewLine _
    & "äðäìä" & vbNewLine _
    & "îç÷ø" & vbNewLine _
    & "ôéúåç" & vbNewLine _
    & "ùéåå÷" & vbNewLine _
    & "ñééáø"

    Title = "Selection of Index" ' Define title.
    MyInput = InputBox(Msg, Title)
    Select Case MyInput
    Case "äëðñåú", "äðäìä", "îç÷ø", "ôéúåç", "ùéåå÷", "ñééáø"

       Cells(i, 3) = MyInput
       Case Else
        MsgBox "not ok"


    End Select

Else

End If

Next

End Sub
```

at the vlookup application I get a runtime error 1004, anyone has any idea why and how to fix it?

thnx in advance

Comment: [Excel VBA - Reference Guide: Debugging](http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/debugging.htm)

Comment: link not working

Comment: Works for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
countnonblank2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)
```

should be

```
countnonblank2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(nuRange)
```

as you're counting nonblank cells in column B, and using it in the `VLOOKUP` function.

edit:
There is more at fault in your code. `myRange` is not declared as a range but as a variant! A declaration like `Dim a,b,c as range` only defines `c` as a range and `a` and `b` as variants. The correct syntax would be `Dim a as range, b as range, c as range`.
In your code `countnonblank1, myRange,inpt, Msg, Title` all need editing.

Comment: sorry man, it didn't help, still the same error msg.
this is driving me insane...

Comment: it's like i'm referencing something wrong in the vlookup, and i just can't figure it out...so frustrating